# Проверить наличие класса у элемента

Tags: javascript

Привет! помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
Необходиомо проверить наличие класса у элемента, и в случае отсутствия класса, добавить его.
вот код:

```
    var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0; i<cells.length;i++){
    cells[i].addEventListener('click', selectDate);
}
function selectDate(){
    if(cells.classList.contains('active')) {
        return false;
    }else{
        cells.classList.add('active');
    }
}
```

тут полный код [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/fwxuf5ea/22/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`selectDate` - это функция обработчика, внутри нее *this* указывает на элемент по которому кликнули. Все что нужно, заменить *cells* на *this*

```
function selectDate(){
    if(this.classList.contains('active')) {
        return false;
    }else{
        this.classList.add('active');
    }
}
```

Кроме того, в данном случае проверка необязательна, так-как *classList.add* не добавляет класс, если он уже присутствует.

Comment: спасибо! теперь понятно